# LoginStatus redirect works only in explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, loginstatus

I work with the Membership system in my project's masterpage and I'm trying to implement a LoginStatus control that will allow to loging/logout.

The control's login/logout link only works in internet explorer, but in firefox or chrome it's not clickable. is there anything I should add?

**here is my control:**

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                                    LoginText="התחבר" 
                                    LogoutText="התנתק" 
                                    LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
                                    LogoutAction="Redirect"/>
```

**EDIT**

I tried to move the LoginStatus control to the footer and the link works. Probably just like Bartdude mentioned, it's a css problem. But I have no idea what is causing it.
I'm sure you guys will know.

**Here is my html part:**

```
 <header>
            <div class="clearfix""></div>
            <div class="site_logo"><img src="assets/img/act_logo2.jpg" style="height:100px; width:200px;" />
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr class="customHR" />
            <div class="TopNav">
                <div id="aspLoginStatus">
                    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString ="Welcome, {0}" />

                    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                                    LoginText="התחבר" 
                                    LogoutText="התנתק" 
                                    LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
                                    LogoutAction="Redirect" 
                                     />


                </div>
                <ul>
                <li><a visible=false id="profile_link_master" runat="server">פרופיל אישי</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a visible=false id="profile_link" runat="server" onclick="redirect_to_profile()">פרופיל אישי</a></li>
                            <li><a visible=false id="layout_link" runat="server" onclick="redirect_to_layout()">עיצוב פרופיל</a></li>
                            <li><a visible=false id="search_profile_link" runat="server" onclick="redirect_to_search()">פרופיל חברי העמותה</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <li><a visible=false id="user_link" runat="server" href="create_user.aspx">ניהול משתמשים</a></li>
                    <li><a visible=false id="report_link" runat="server" href="report.aspx">דו"חות</a></li>


                    <li><a visible=false id="members_link" runat="server" href="#">חברי העמותה</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a visible=false id="search_link" runat="server" href="search_mem.aspx">חיפוש חבר</a></li>
                            <li><a visible=false id="mail_link" runat="server" href="e_mail.aspx">שלח מייל</a></li>
                            <li><a visible=false id="candidates_link" runat="server" href="Candidates.aspx">מועמדים ממתינים</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a id="join_link" runat="server" href="join_act.aspx">הצטרף לאקט</a></li>
                    <li><a id="info_link" runat="server" href="#">מידע שימושי</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="about_link" runat="server" href="web_site.aspx">אודות העמותה</a></li>
                            <li><a id="form_link" runat="server" href="forms.aspx">טפסים</a></li>
                            <li><a id="insurance_link" runat="server" href="insurance.aspx">ביטוחים</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a visible=false id="home_link" runat="server" href="events.aspx">דף הבית</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

**Here is the relevant css:**

```
header {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
   /* background-color: #D0D0D0; */
   moz-box-shadow: 1px 10px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 10px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 10px #000000; 
    height:100px;

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7D2BA6 0%, #000000 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7D2BA6 0%, #000000 100%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7D2BA6 0%, #000000 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #7D2BA6), color-stop(1, #000000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7D2BA6 0%, #000000 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7D2BA6 0%, #000000 100%);
}

    header .site_logo {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    header .TopNav {
        display: block;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    }

        header .TopNav #aspLoginStatus {
            float:right;
            margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    header .TopNav, ul {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
        text-align:center;
    }

        header .TopNav ul li {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0px;
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 110%;
            text-align:right;
        }

            header .TopNav ul li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }

            header .TopNav ul li ul { /* SubNav Styling */
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 10px;
                min-width: 100px;
                max-width: 200px;
                background-color: #F0F0F0;
                display: none;
            }

                header .TopNav ul li ul li { /* SubNav Styling */
                    display: block;
                    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
                }

                    header .TopNav ul li ul li a { /* SubNav Styling */
                        display: block;
                    }

            header .TopNav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0 5px 0 2px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

                header .TopNav ul li a:hover {
                    color: #0FA2BC;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had a similar issue I couldn't understand. Of course it's hard to tell with the info we have if you're having the same kind of issue but still...

My problem was actually linked to the HTML integration : the CSS was such that another element overlayed the link, while with a transparent background so you couldn't see it was over.

Another thing I would check is if there's no javascript error. As linkbuttons are basically triggering underlying javascript, it's possible a javascript error because of a IE-only code is preventing other browsers to work correctly.

One thing I'm quite sure is that you shouldn't look for the solution in your server-side code, as the difference seems to be on client side.

Comment: You were right, it was something with the css. when I move it to the footer it works. but I don't understand why. I added the html and css to the post, maybe you can see what's wrong

Comment: I would suggest you to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML + CSS, it wil be easier for you to reproduce and for us to see what the problem is. Of course you'll need to put the HTML generated source, cause it's impossible to debug with aspx source as we don't know how the usercontrols will render. P.S : I would suggest accepting my answer and open a new question to get more attention. A 7 days old question won't raise many attention ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a z-index property, and so the control was above all css.